# Using TypeDescriptor in place of TryParse

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, casting, tryparse

I am trying to replicate TryParse for generic types and thought that TypeDescriptor might give me what I am after. So I came up with the following test case but it is failing, just wondering if anyone knows where I am going wrong.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        string value = "Test";
        Guid resultValue;
        var result = this.TryConvert(value, out resultValue); 
    } 

    public bool TryConvert<T>(string value, out T resultValue)
    { 
        var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        if (converter.IsValid(value))
        {
            resultValue = (T)converter.ConvertFrom(value);
            return true;
        }
        resultValue = default(T);
        return false;
    }
```

Note, I don't want to use a try catch block.

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: Where is it failing?  Is converter null?  Is the IsValid call returning false?

Comment: IsValid always returns true. Hence this line fails "resultValue = (T)converter.ConvertFrom(value);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN documentation for `TypeConverter.IsValid`:

> The `IsValid` method is used to validate a value within the type rather than to determine if value can be converted to the given type.

So it will only check the type of the value, not whether the value is correct input that can be parsed.

Also see [this Connect ticket](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=93559).

Comment: EnumConverter, NullableConverter, and UriTypeConverter are the only ones that actually make use of IsValid.